# How to download a single large file over sftp or http etc using multiple simultaneous connections

Tags: command-line, download, http, sftp, parallel-processing

Is there a command line tool which supports both multiple simultaneous connections and multiple network protocols (ftp, http etc)?

Here is a practical example:

I have a large backup file on an ssh server I want to transfer to my current machine.
The file download is taking too long, so I want to use multiple simultaneous network connections to speed it up.  Assume the ssh server is not heavily loaded.

Downloads of **multiple files/URLs** using simultaneous connections are **not relevant** to this question.

I do not want to have to write any code to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [lftp](https://lftp.yar.ru/) program can handle both multiple network protocols and simultaneous connections.

**Protocol support:**

Lftp supports the following protocols:

- ftp
- sftp
- http and https
- bittorrent

Further information on ftps etc [here](https://lftp.yar.ru/features.html).

**Parallel downloads:**

To download a single large file located at `<URI>` using 2 simultaneous connections:

```
lftp -c "pget -c -n 2 <URI>"
```

The first `-c` option specifies the command(s) to run.  `pget` establishes a file transfer using several parallel connections.  The second `-c` option means continue transfer if this transfer had previously been interrupted.  The `-n` option limits the maximum number of connections to use.

There is more information on commands and options in the online [man page](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html).

**Warning:** This can speedup transfers, but loads the network and servers heavily.  Speedups are contingent on network and server conditions.

To address the practical example in the question:

```
lftp -c "pget -c -n 2 sftp://user@192.168.0.1/~/backups/large.tar.gz"
```

This example downloads a large backup file over ssh (sftp) with 2 simultaneous connections.  It assumes you have password-less ssh login setup.

Note: Lftp can also be used in an interactive mode; similar to other ftp commands.

Comment: As you've answered your own question - could you give figures on how beneficial parallel transfers is? i.e: transfer rate of a single connection vs. multiple (2 or 4)

Comment: Easier said than done. Rigorous benchmarking would require multiple runs with multiple files sizes and multiple connections etc and I cannot control network conditions. Benchmarks do not necessarily transfer from test to production environments. Anecdotally, I see a bit less than 2 times speed increase when using 2 connections on an active internal work network while transferring multi-GB files. Diminishing returns set in with large numbers of connections as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

[`aria2`](https://aria2.github.io/) supports multiple connections and FTP, HTTP and SFTP (amont others).

For example:

```
aria2c -j ${num_concurrent} "${uri}"
```

---

> I want to use multiple simultaneous network connections to speed it up

Unless the server is configured to throttle individual connections, running multiple parallel downloads may not give any benefit... in fact, it may negatively affect your throughput.

Using standard tools (i.e: `rsync`, `scp`, `curl`) will *typically* give you what you're after.

If dropped connections / partial transfers are an issue, then a utility like this can be beneficial, but note that `rsync --partial` will also help.

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing a dropped connection with lftp, but I mostly use it on an internal network.

Comment: Interesting to note that aria2 can download from multiple sources like so: aria2c http://a/f.iso ftp://b/f.iso